# Unable to find type selector in correct namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a XAML Page in my Windows Phone 8.1 App, i am trying to use a TypeSelector on a ListView. I have created the TypeSelectors like this

```
namespace MiLocal.Views.Selectors
{
    public class FilterListingTypeSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate TypeATemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TypeBTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var element = item as Filter;
            return TypeATemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

And i then reference it in my XML file as shown below

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeATemplate">

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeBTemplate">

    </DataTemplate>
    <selectors:FilterListingTypeSelector x:Key="TypeSelector" TypeATemplate="{StaticResource TypeATemplate}" TypeBTemplate="{StaticResource TypeBTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Finally for completeness below is my using statement from page attributes.

```
xmlns:selectors="using:MiLocal.Views.Selectors"
```

I get the error

```
Error   1   The name "FilterListingTypeSelector" does not exist in the namespace "using:MiLocal.Views.Selectors".
```

Comment: xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:MiLocal.Views.Selectors"

Comment: Creates a new error and still have the same one as before but just referencing the new namespace

Error 3 Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'MiLocal.Views.Selectors' that could not be found.

Comment: try adding this within your `xmlns`: xmlns:selectors="using:MiLocal.Views.Selectors;assembly=MiLocal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and Xaml are correct for a Windows Phone Runtime app. Make sure you built the FilterListingTypeSelector object. The designer won't find the class if it hasn't been build. If you still have trouble after a clean build then you may need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks for the help!! Totally new to XAML and was being my head off a wall. Everything i had found online was saying i was going in the right direction :)